# SHFileOperation fails to copy the all files from the source folder

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Recently I faced with very strange behavior of SHFileOperation Windows API (in Windows 7 OS). A simple C++ code

```
TCHAR szFrom[_MAX_PATH+1];
_tcscpy(szFrom, From.c_str());
::PathAppend(szFrom, _T("*.*"));
*(szFrom + _tcslen(szFrom) + 1) = 0;

TCHAR szTo[_MAX_PATH+1];
_tcscpy(szTo, To.c_str());
*(szTo + _tcslen(szTo) + 1) = 0;

// Perform Copy operation
SHFILEOPSTRUCT Op = { GetDesktopWindow(), FO_COPY, szFrom, szTo,
                      FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR | FOF_NOCOPYSECURITYATTRIBS, 0, 0, 0 };
int Res = ::SHFileOperation(&Op);
if (Res != 0 || Op.fAnyOperationsAborted)
{
    CString Message;
    Message.Format(_T("Error code = %d"), Res);
    AfxMessageBox(Message, MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
}
```

copies only a part of files from network folder ("From" parameter) to local folder ("To" parameter). I tried the all combinations of "FOF" flags, tried to run as administrator - does not help. The return code from SHFileOperation is always 1223. I also checked my access rights to the network folder - I have the all necessary rights: read, write, modify and execute.

Originally I had 0 for the owning window handle, and changed it to the desktop window by someone's advice found in my Google search. The FOF_ flags shown here are also the result of many variations I tried in attempt to understand what is happening. The number of files copied and sub-folders created varies from trial to trial, sometimes progress dialog appears and sometimes (rarely) it even succeed to copy all the files. But I never get an error message.

What can be a reason for such behavior and is there a way to overcome that?

PS: I saw some similar questions, but no one had intelligible answer.

Comment: 1223 is `ERROR_CANCELLED`: "*The function prompted the user for additional information, but the user canceled the request.*"

Comment: Don't make the desktop window be the owner window.

Comment: For starters you are using MFC, so that framework maybe have a class that you need for.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I know that, but it doesn't help much. As you understand, I didn't cancelled any request and there was no any prompt from the function.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I tried to give 0 for hwnd member in conjunction with FOF_NO_UI flag. I tried also to create a real hidden owner window. But all that do not change the observed behavior.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to change the expected behaviour. I'm just telling you that using the desktop window as the owner of one of your windows is wrong. Don't do that. Since you don't want to show UI, you can pass 0.

Comment: Now, I next suggest that you remove `FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR` and see what UI is shown.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I do want the GUI from SHFileOperation, otherwise I would already use recursively FindFirstFile/FindNextFile/CopyFile. I also tested the variant

 `SHFILEOPSTRUCT Op = { 0, FO_COPY, szFrom, szTo, 0, 0, 0, 0 };`
 
The result was the same. The number of files copied and sub-folders created varies from trial to trial, sometimes progress dialog appears and sometimes (rarely) it even succeed to copy all the files. But I never get an error message.